# How do I check if table exists before alter table

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I need query to update all tables and set `ENGINE = INNODB` To many databases. But some of the databases don't have all the same tables; some databases have more tables than others.

So the problem is that

```
ALTER TABLE `ads` ENGINE = INNODB;
ALTER TABLE `modules` ENGINE = INNODB;
ALTER TABLE `ad_extras` ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Throws an error when the table `modules` doe snot exist. I see that I cannot make a direct IF statement' I tried:

```
IF EXISTS (SHOW TABLES LIKE 'modules') BEGIN
ALTER TABLE `modules` ENGINE = INNODB;
END IF
```

But it throws

> Unrecognized statement type (near IF EXISTS)

Any ideas?

Comment: retrieve the information about table existence from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA_TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-tables-table.html).

Answer (score 2):

If this is just an ad-hoc task,

```
select concat('ALTER ', TABLE_NAME, " ENGINE = INNODB;") 
from information_schema.TABLES 
where TABLE_SCHEMA = '<your schema>';
```

Execute the output again.

Answer (score 0):

If Exists works only in a stored procedure.

a fixed edition of Jacob's answer:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

select group_concat(concat('ALTER Table ', TABLE_NAME, ' ENGINE = INNODB;') SEPARATOR '\n')
from information_schema.TABLES 
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema_name' and TABLE_TYPE<>'VIEW';
```

This will give you a script to copy and run separately.

Answer (score -3):

What about testing it simple as this query :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `yourtablename`;
```

Comment: They want to alter the table not drop it.